# Magento Quickstart installations

Tags: magento, themes

I need you help as regards a question. I have a running magento store, and I want to install a new theme. I tried manual installation, but I am having problems with the Sm Shopby extension.  I want to use the quickstart option, but I DONT KNOW IF I WILL LOOSE existing products on site? IF I do this, will it mean I have two magento installations?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because Stack Overflow is a [programming-related](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) Q&A site. Your question is not about programming. Perhaps you should post it on http://magento.stackexchange.com instead?

Answer (score 1):

If you choose quick installation then it will install new Magento with theme so instead quick manual is better Please specify which problem you facing while manual installation ?

There are many possibility like theme not configure properly, permission issue etc...